# how i can set middleware for some views in django?

Tags: python, django

i have a django project with 50 url (in 1 application).
i would set a custom middleware for 20 urls.
when add middleware to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES , this set for all urls .
How should this be done?
(i use last version of python and djnago)

Comment: Maybe write a condition in the middleware to check request url and only run its code for the urls you want.

Comment: That sounds more like a job for a decorator.

Answer (score 5):

You can utilize decorators, view's decorators behave similarly to middlewares, simple ex:

```
from functools import wraps

def custom_view_decorator(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Any preprocessing conditions..etc.
        return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

Usage in `views.py`:

```
@custom_view_decorator
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # view code, return response
```

Answer (score 2):

for starters you could do something like this:

```
class BlockUrlsMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    REDIRECT_URL = reverse("not_allowed")

    WHITELISTED_URLS = [
        "/your/custom/views/urls",
        "/your/custom/apis/urls",
    ]

    def process_request(self, request):

        if request.path in self.WHITELISTED_URLS:
            return None
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.REDIRECT_URL)
```

few points to Note:

1. return `None` means everything is good and serve this request.
2. return `HttpResponseRedirect` means URLs are accessed which are not allowed and block this request by redirecting it to your default URLs (that you need to set) in this case `REDIRECT_URL`.

Answer (score 0):

you can either add a check condition to your middleware which is not recommended(since you cannot determine whether this middleware is working or not without reading it's code). or create a decorator for those views, decorator job is exactly this.